# Invalid random wallpaper directory in awsetbg

Tags: desktop-background, awesome

I'm using the awesome wm and awsetbg to draw the background. Suddenly, for a mysterious reason, it doesn't work (awsetbg /some/file.jpg), and when I try to get it to use a random directory (awsetbg -r /path/to/pics/dir) it says "invalid random wallpaper directory." Why is that, and how can I fix it? The directory doesn't contain anything but image files.

Update: I tried both awsetbg -r ~/Pictures and awsetbg -r /usr/share/backgrounds, but neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-r` without a wallpaper setter installed awsetbg will set the directory to "#535d6c" which is invalid, install any wallpaper setter to fix it.

`sudo apt-get install feh`

Instead of feh you can try chbg, xsri, display, Esetroot, wmsetbg, xsetbg, xli, qiv, xv, hsetroot, habak, fvwm-root or icewmbg.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-R` not `-r`

Worked for me.